# Is there objective reason against using braces even where not necessary?

Tags: c

Both kernel coding style and gnome's C style guide states that:

```
Do not unnecessarily use braces where a single statement will do.

if (condition)
        action();
```

but at the same time it **should** be sometimes used, as in `else` branch of:

```
if (condition) {
        do_this();
        do_that();
} else {
        otherwise();
}
```

Is there any technical or usability reasons to prefer it this way? Are there any objective reasons not to put the braces there everytime?

Comment: Readability. If you sometimes have the braces, and other times do not, the code is not easily read. IMO with modern storage, editors, and compilers being as they are, there is no reason to omit them.

Comment: The only reason to always use braces everywhere which I think all users of C would agree on, is to protect against bad macros. If the use of macros and their style is heavily regulated (or better yet forbidden), then even that reason becomes subjective.

Comment: In safety-critical (and security-critical) applications, coding standards (like, e.g. MISRA) demand that braces are used for every if/else/for/while/... block. These standards are backed up by scientific studies and/or long-term industrial experience. Let's believe them, and use braces. @Someprogrammerdude - If you feel code is getting less readable, you've likely written functions too complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only stylistic and ease-of-editing-related reasons.

Whether you omit the brace or not, C compilers must act as if the braces were there (+ a pair around the whole iteration statement (`if` or `if`-`else`)).

[6.8.4p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4p3):

> A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the
> scope of its enclosing block. Each associated substatement is also a
> block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the selection
> statement.

The existence of these implicit blocks can be nicely demonstrated with enums:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    enum{ e=0};
    printf("%d\n", (int)e);
    if(1) printf("%d\n", (sizeof(enum{e=1}),(int)e));
    if(sizeof(enum{e=2})) printf("%d\n", (int)e);
    printf("%d\n", (int)e);

    //prints 0 1 2 0
}
```

A similar rule also exists for iteration statements: [6.8.5p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5p5).

These implicit blocks also mean that a compound literal defined inside an iteration or selection statement is limited to such an implicit block. That is why example [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p15](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p15) from the standard puts a compound literal in between a label an explicit `goto` instead of simply using a `while` statement, which would limit the scope of the literal, regardless of whether or not explicit braces were used.

While it may be tempting, don't ever do:

```
if (Ptr) Ptr = &(type){0}; //WRONG way to provide a default for Ptr
```

The above leads to UB (and actually nonworking wit `gcc -O3`) because of the scoping rules.

The correct way to do the above is either with:

```
type default_val = {0};
if (Ptr) Ptr = &default_val; //OK
```

or with:

```
Ptr = Ptr ? Ptr : &(type){0}; //OK
```

These implicit blocks are new in C99 and the inner ones (for selection statements (=ifs)) are well rationalized ([C99RationaleV5.10.pdf](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), section 6.8) as aids in refactoring, preventing braces that are added from previously unbraced branches from changing meaning.

The outermost branch around the whole selection statements doesn't appear to be so well rationalized, unfortunately (more accurately, it's not rationalized at all). It appears copied from the rule for iterations statements, which appears to copy the C++ rules where `for`-loop-local variables are destructed at the very end of the whole for loop (as if the for loop were braced).

(Unfortunately, I think that for selection statement the outermost implicit {} does more harm than good as it prevents you from having macros that stack-allocate in just the scope of the caller but also need a check, because then you can only check such macros with `?:` but not with `if`, which is weird.)

Comment: Thanks. This means `?:` rather than `if` must be used for the kind of usage I had in mind.

Comment: Note that those rules don't apply to the msvc compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's one special case in which braces **do need to be used:**  Suppose you have the following code:

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        f();
else g();
```

As it is indented, one could assume the `else g();` statement belongs to the first `if(a)` statement, but C syntax rules say that it is interpreted as (now with braces):

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        f();
    }
else {
    g();
}
}
```

which actually means:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        f();
    }
    else {
        g();
    }
}
```

in case you wanted the other possibility, then you **must use braces.**  For example you can write it this way:

```
if (a) {
    if (b)
        f();
}
else
    g();
```

which actually means:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        f();
    }
}
else {
    g();
}
```

## Note

As all elementary programming books recommend:  If you are in doubt about operator precedence, then use parentheses; if you extend that to statements coding, if you are in doubt, use braces! :)

Answer (score 0):

I hate those "if in doubt" guidelines with a passion. They engender laziness that pushes the cost onto the code reader.

Such guidelines lead to code that is more cluttered, slower to read, and therefore harder to debug.

If in doubt go and read the precedence table.
If still hesitating, write some test code to verify the interpretation.
Repeat this every time you code until precedence becomes second nature.
When you are sure you have a firm grasp of precedence, then and only then write the production code.

If you really can't manager that, then always break up your statements so that they contain no more than two levels of grouping parentheses in any one statement. If that means you have to make up lots of temporary variable names, that's a good thing.